# IIS 7 - ISAPI error "Printer selected is not valid": how configure an ISAPI pool for see the printer?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, isapi

I have a isapi *.dll made with Delphi that make and return a PDF on http request.
The code works if i build it in a standalone exe, but on a isapi it raise an exception: "Printer selected is not valid".

It seem a **ApplicationPoolIdentity** issue.

Googling the issue i have found this explanation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4619757/2936170):

> This is likely due to Session 0 Isolation, which was introduced in
>   Vista. Services always run in Session 0, but in XP and earlier, the
>   first user to log in also runs in Session 0, thus allowing services to
>   access that user's desktop (thus allowing for "Interactive" services)
>   and resources (like shares and printers). In Vista onwards, users
>   never run in Session 0 anymore, so services do not have access to
>   user-specific resources anymore. A service has to impersonate the user
>   account it wants to access.

I have also builded the same code in a windows service and installed with admin privilege, it works!

The question is, **how configure an ISAPI pool for see the printer**?

Answer (score 1):

Respond my self.

the correct pool identy is **LocalSystem**